# A problem with reported speech

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, reported-speech

I was wondering which tense should be used in the following indirect questions?

**First case:** 
1.1. Where are you going? → I ask**ed** where you **are** going 
1.2. Where are you going? → I ask**ed** where you **were** going

**Second case:** 
2.1. Why are you crying? → He ask**ed** me why I **am** crying 
2.2. Why are you crying? → He ask**ed** me why I **was** crying

I think since the tense of main verb within the indirect question is simple past, the correct sentences would be "#1.2" and "#2.2".

I wonder if you could correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: (Native speakers *normally* "backshift" the verb in contexts like your examples, so the second option is "more correct".)

Comment: If you're interested in the syntax, the _where_ and _why_ expressions are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions).